# tool to manage multiple tomcat servers

Tags: tomcat, server, production-environment

I am in the search of tool to manage multiple tomcat servers , i have something like 20 server , with each 5 webapps , deployment are taking very long time , i'm looking for a way to push webbapps to tomcat very quickly.

I already read some subjects on it , most of people recommends maven to do it , the problem is most of the server can't have theirs port open on the internet , so the tomcat manager can't be exposed on the web.

So i thought of something like a central console where all the tomcats connects to it , and from there i can redeploy modules.

If you have infos or recommandations i will be happy.

Thank you

Comment: Sorry for the grammar mistakes :s

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking for the [Tomcat Farm Web Deployer](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/cluster-deployer.html).